Alternative Part Choice Altium 24.1.2 for HX711
I am looking for a way to add a Part Choice for the HX711 IC SOP-16 package that is not sold by classical manufacturer like Mouser, Digikey... I found a link on amazon and I'd like to use it but I can't find where I can add the path. I created a component for the SOP-16 package IC and I added some parameters. I've never done something like this before and I checked on the Internet but I can't find a way to solve this quickly.

https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/1836471/0/0/1/hx711.html

You can edit or add a Manufacturer link in the "Properties" panel of the SCH library for the particular part you've created. You can create a new parameters as link type if you want something dedicated to non-manufacturer sources, for example you could call it "Supplier Link". If you create your components consistently then such links will all be exported under one column in a spreadsheet. If you vary the parameter names at all, they'll not be.
